# Color values change from one Photoshop document to another

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I've got two PS documents, both are in RGB 16 bit mode. One is a photo in .jpg the other a .psd document.

When I select a color with the eyedropper tool from the 1st document to use in the second document the color value changes to a more muddier color. How can i prevent this when both the color modes and bit depth are the same? I'm pulling my hair out here....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something to check: When you eyedropper a layer, it can sometimes pick up adjustment layers or ignore blend modes. If so, option-click with the eyedropper tool to pick the colour created by the flattened layers.

This also might be related to colour profiles. Ensure both documents are using the same colour profile `Edit > Assign profile`. If you want to permanently convert the colours in the document use `Edit > Convert to profile`. sRGB is usually the best choice for working on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I will go out on a limb and say that I believe you are trusting the 16-bit JPEG too much. JPEG format is an 8-bit image format and will differ from the 16-bit PSD file. The reason for converting a file to JPEG is to end up with a smaller file size. That in turn is achieved by lower bit depth and lossy compression.